# Filter table with logical operations using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to implement table filter with And/Or logical operations. Now the table is filtering based on individual datepicker and select field. If I select AND the table should show both datepicker and select field results, if I select OR either of one should display. Is it possible to achieve it in jquery. Any help is appreciated.

```js
    $(document).on("change", "#datepicker .created_on , select", function() {
   var dataVal = $("#datepicker .created_on").datepicker('getDate');
   dataVal = $.datepicker.formatDate("d/m/y", dataVal);
   var select_value = $("#nameselect select").val();
   var logic = $("select.logic").val();
   $("#myTable tr:not('#table-header')").hide();
   if (select_value != "" && dataVal != "") {
     $("#myTable tbody > tr").each(function() {
       var data_type = $(this).data('type');
       var datess = $(this).find("td:eq(3) label").text()
       var condition = (logic == "1") ? ((data_type == select_value) && (datess == dataVal)) : ((data_type == select_value) || (datess == dataVal))
       
       if (condition) {
         $(this).show();
       }
     });
   } else if (dataVal != "" && select_value == "") {
     console.log("dwd")
     $("label:contains('" + dataVal + "')").each(function() {
       $(this).closest('tr').show();
     });

   } else if (dataVal == "" && select_value != "") {

     $("[data-type=" + select_value + "]").each(function() {
       $(this).show();
     });
   }



 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

  <div style="display:inline-flex;">
    <label>logic</label>
    <select style="width:60px;" required="" class="logic">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="1">OR</option>
      <option value="2">AND</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left:10px;display:inline-flex;" id="nameselect">
    <label for="value">Name</label>
    <select style="width:120px;" id="mylist" class='form-control' required="">
      <option value="">select</option>
      <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
      <option value="John">John</option>
      <option value="Martin">Martin</option>
      <option value="Rozi">Rozi</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <table class="" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="margin-top:10px;" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr id="table-header">
        <th><label> NAME</label></th>
        <th><label> TYPE</label></th>
        <th><label>Doc</label></th>
        <th style="margin-left:10px"><label>Date</label></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="">
      <tr class="" data-type="Mary">
        <td><label>Mary</label></td>
        <td><label>text</label></td>
        <td><label>word</label></td>
        <td><label style="margin-left:10px">1/1/21</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" data-type="John">
        <td><label>John</label></td>
        <td><label>text</label></td>
        <td><label>word</label></td>
        <td><label style="margin-left:10px">31/1/21</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" data-type="Martin">
        <td><label>Martin</label></td>
        <td><label>text</label></td>
        <td><label>word</label></td>
        <td><label style="margin-left:10px">21/2/21</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="" data-type="Rozi">
        <td><label>Rozi</label></td>
        <td><label>text</label></td>
        <td><label>word</label></td>
        <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/20</label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: HI, `and` here means both condition should match and `or` means any one can also match am i right ?

Comment: @Swati exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use check if the `logic` select value is `1` or `2` depending on this use `&&` or `||` operator and show required trs .

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(document).on("change", "#datepicker .created_on , select", function() {
  var dataVal = $("#datepicker .created_on").datepicker('getDate');
  dataVal = $.datepicker.formatDate("d/m/y", dataVal);
  var select_value = $("#nameselect select").val(); //get select value
  var logic = $("select.logic").val();
  //check if both are not both empty
  if (select_value != "" && dataVal != "") {
    $("#myTable tr:not('#table-header')").hide();
    $("#myTable tbody > tr").each(function() {
      var data_type = $(this).data('type'); //get data attr value
      var datess = $(this).find("td:eq(3) label").text() //get date value
      //compare 
      var condition = (logic == "1") ? ((data_type == select_value) && (datess == dataVal)) : ((data_type == select_value) || (datess == dataVal))
      if (condition) {
        $(this).show(); //show
      }
    });
  } else {
    //show all..
    $("#myTable tr").show();
    //or some other logic you need .
  }



});



(function($) {
  $('.datepicker').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      onClose: function() {
        //triggerFocus();
      }
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="datepicker1" style="display:inline-flex;" id="datepicker">
  <label for="datepicker">Date</label>
  <input type="text" style="width:120px;" class="created_on required datepicker" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" required="">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-flex;">
  <label>logic</label>
  <select style="width:60px;" required="" class="logic">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="1">AND</option>
    <option value="2">OR</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:10px;display:inline-flex;" id="nameselect">
  <label for="value">Name</label>
  <select style="width:120px;" id="mylist" class='form-control' required="">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Martin">Martin</option>
    <option value="Rozi">Rozi</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table class="" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="margin-top:10px;" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header">
      <th><label> NAME</label></th>
      <th><label> TYPE</label></th>
      <th><label>Doc</label></th>
      <th style="margin-left:10px"><label>Date</label></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="">
    <tr class="" data-type="Mary">
      <td><label>Mary</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">1/1/21</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="John">
      <td><label>John</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">31/1/21</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Martin">
      <td><label>Martin</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">21/2/21</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" data-type="Rozi">
      <td><label>Rozi</label></td>
      <td><label>text</label></td>
      <td><label>word</label></td>
      <td><label style="margin-left:10px">5/10/20</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: with the above code filtering the table via datepicker is not working. Thx for the idea though

Comment: you can add that code in else part to check if dateval is not null and select box is null then use your code which you have to filter date.

Comment: Hi , try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8pzr1yot/1/) see if that works .